# A strange process called "watchbog" is hogging my entire CPU and I can't get rid of it

Tags: linux, debian, malware

This process that has come out of nowhere is hogging my CPU and I have no clue what it is or how to get rid of it. You can see in the image below what it's doing:

[image: Process that's hogging my cpu]

What is this process? How can I get rid of it?

Every time I kill the process, it spawns back up within a minute or less.

Comment: Multi-posted at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199553/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729222/ .

Comment: Well I was told to post in security instead of stack overflow and then I realized it might make most sense here.

Comment: This is a virus, if this is on a production system somewhere you need to initiate your disaster response plan if you have one. If not, take a forensic image of the server and spin down the machine and start over from scratch. Install from a known good image of the OS and use backups from an earlier date when this process was not present. Contact your local authorities and everyone relevant in your organization. User Michael Prokopec's advice is solid. From the other threads those users have sound advice too. It is going to be easier to start from scratch than save this one to be honest.

Comment: https://sudhakarbellamkonda.blogspot.com/2018/11/blocking-watchbog-malwareransomware.html

Comment: @kemotep So, this is just a test machine in a small office and I just literally a few weeks ago started from scratch because of a virus doing the same thing under a different name. And now, same thing a few weeks later... What am I doing wrong? My root password is very secure and not possible to guess by any bruteforce attempt. How is someone repeatedly installing malware on my machine? I don't have the experience for this...

Comment: Well, you could be installing from a bad iso. A few years ago, Linux Mint's site was hacked and for a few days distributed bad isos. You could have ssh open to the internet, you could have installed or downloaded a package from a shady source. You could be victim of a targeted attack. Do any other devices on the network exhibit odd behavior? What services does the server run and are they accessible to the internet? Root can be "secure" but if one can gain access via a vulnerable user or service one can escalate to root or exploit other facets. It is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "ssh open to the internet"? I do use ssh often to remote in. I don't have anything out of the ordinary I don't think, just Apache services mostly. I am using this machine for Nutch to crawl the web - could this open me to exploits? No other machines are acting strange. I can't imagine why it'd be a targeted attack, it's a useless machine really. Has nothing of value on it. Oh and the ISO is Debian 9.4 directly from their site.

Comment: What I mean is that anyone in the world can attempt to access your machine via SSH. SSH is most secure when security is applied in layers: key based authentication, no root logins allowed, an Access Control List limited to specific devices authenticated on the network. If you need to access this from home or outside the office you use a VPN, and further lock down access, etc etc. I do not know the specifics of Nutch, but are you installing it from the Debian repos? If it comes from a third party source and not Debian it could have been compromised. It itself could also be vulnerable to attack.

Comment: To be clear as well, very rarely uncommon packages in the main repositories can get hijacked however Debian development and package management is very transparent so this is hard however an additional attack vector could be a compromised mirror that you are using.

Comment: So then is there not really any reliable way to determine where this came from? I'll fresh install if I have to but what's the point if this is going to just happen again.  I don't think Nutch would be compromised, it's directly from Apache. But I suppose it itself could have some vulnerability baked in. But what you say about SSH, I may look into that - the key based authentication. As is, I'm just logging in with root and the password. I guess that's quite silly on my part.

Comment: I've done what Michael said and so far the virus is being kept at bay. I'm currently running and antivirus and searching all my files using grep for "watchbog."

Comment: Yeah you should not be running things as root, you should have an unprivileged user that you use that can elevate permissions with `sudo` or by switching over to root with `su -`. Try not installing Nutch and see what happens. Perhaps Nutch is scrapping compromised websites that are serving you the malware.

Comment: OK - thank you very much for the advice. I'm taking all into consideration.

Comment: Related: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](//serverfault.com/q/218005)

Comment: @kemotep: if the virus comes from compromised package, it won't be from compromised mirrors. Debian packages are GPG signed, and unless you ignored or disabled all the security warnings you'll get trying to install, or you added the attackers' signing key to the system, you're not going to get compromised packages from compromised mirrors.

Comment: @LieRyan I understand, however I have seen plenty of installation guides that tell people to ignore the gpg key check or otherwise reduce the security of the system by downloading from a random site and piping the output to a root shell.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a virus or worm of some kind. Can't find anything about it on the web so you might have close to the first case. It is trying to masquerade as watchdog which is an anti-virus and anti-mailware process. So I would call a major antivirus company and make them aware, send them a copy. Do the same for your distro's watchdog maintainer. This can be found in the package information for watchdog.

- The only thing I can suggest to try to remove this is check all of your startup lists and check for changes. Look for the process script. Like, `whereis watchbog`, if it gives you the location of the binary, write it down. Boot to a live cd/usb and then find that file on your disk and remove it.
- Also look through your startups again.
- Turn your firewall on and set it to block outgoing temporarily look to see if your system is looking to re-download it after removal. If it is, there is a hidden process that is making sure you stay infected. Either track it down and remove, or get the files you need off and quarantine them and scan them, make sure none of them have the execute bit set unless you know what they do.
- Then DBAN the drive and reinstall your OS, and then use clamAV, chkrootkit and rkhunter. You must either set up the clamav daemon or run manualy like the others to maintain a clean system.
- Rescan the files you copied off the system before the DBAN, to make sure they are clean, before using them again.

Comment: Whoa boy... OK, thanks for the elaborate reply. I will look into this as best I can (I'm not terribly familiar with Linux but might be enough).

Comment: Just to mention, watchbog is in /bin/watchbog but when I delete it, it reappears a bit later.

Comment: Looks like it is trying to reinstall its self. Try to make a file with that name before it comes back or write a script to mv that file to watchdog.bak and your file to its place, that may cripple the infection because then the file then already exists make sure your version is read only after the move.

Comment: I've created my own watchbog file under root permissions and it seems to have accomplished what you said it might. Thank you for that. So at the very least the virus is being temporarily kept at bay.

Comment: I hope you can find a permanent fix soon.

Comment: When a trojan (probably a bitcoin miner) is running as root, the system has been severely compromised.  The solution is _NOT_ to try to find and delete the malware. The solution is to take the system off line as soon as possible and then do a _complete_ reinstall.  See e.g. [How do I deal with a compromised server?](//serverfault.com/q/218005)

Comment: I will fresh install then, thank you. Just don't know what I'm doing wrong to let this in a second time.